# Running Cron Scripts From a Sub-directory

Tags: magento-1.9, php, cron

My html directory is becoming bloated so I am trying to reorganize the files. I have a few scripts that I have running on a cron job and I want to move them out of the html directory.

For example:

cronjob: `php /chroot/home/mydomain/html/restock.php`

restock.php:

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app();

my script

?>
```

What I would like is a directory called 'myscripts' or similar and have all my scripts sitting in there. My question is what is the best practice for this and also how would I modify my php scripts and cronjob???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require_once 'abstract.php';

class Mage_Shell_Restock extends Mage_Shell_Abstract {       
    protected $_stock;
    public function run()
    {
        if(true) {          
            //process your logic
        } else {
            echo $this->usageHelp();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve Usage Help Message
     *
     */
    public function usageHelp()
    {
        return <<<USAGE
Usage:  php -f restock.php -- [options]  
  help              This help
USAGE;
    }
}

$shell = new Mage_Shell_Restock();
$shell->run();
```

You will find **shell** directory in magento root. place this file in **shell** directory.

Add add file in crontab via cpanel or run via ssh.

```
php /chroot/home/mydomain/shell/whateverfilename.php
```